# MySQL Query to Oracle Query Conversion

Tags: mysql, oracle

Consider an sql query like

```
SELECT a, b>now() as expired 
FROM TABLE;
```

where b is a date and checking with current date.

I found out that `now()` should be replaced with `SYSDATE`

but how to write

```
 b > (SYSDATE) as expired
```

for Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle does not have a boolean datatype (neither does MySQL but it simply treats any number not equal to zero as "true"), so you need return a number indicating the expiration as `0` and `1`

```
select a, 
       case 
          when b > sysdate then 1
          else 0
       end as expired
from the_table;
```

Note that Oracle's `DATE` datatype includes the time. So `SYSDATE` returns something like `2013-04-04 14:43:12`. You probably want to use trunc() on the comparison:

```
select a, 
       case 
          when trunc(b) > trunc(sysdate) then 1
          else 0
       end as expired
from the_table;
```

Of course you can return anything in the case statement, not only numbers

```
select a, 
       case 
          when trunc(b) > trunc(sysdate) then 'expired'
          else 'active'
       end as expired
from the_table;
```